# "Error while loading GridDB libraries." when importing GridDB Connector for Python

Tags: python, python-import, griddb

I am using GridDB Connector for Python to start my data analysis script. I first need to import the GridDB connector as follows:

```
import griddb_python
```

I keep getting this error even after installing all the needed dependencies:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 import griddb_python

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'griddb_python'
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this?